# Google Analytics/BigQuery Data Export

Tags: google-analytics, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

We have a requirement where we want to get data from Google Analytics -> Big Query and from Big Query to local SFTP server. What is the right way to export data to SFTP server?

Thanks in advance

Comment: check out [Magnus at Potens.io](https://potensio.zendesk.com) - it has all the tasks needed to implement your requirements including export to FTP as well as to schedule final workflow and all this can be done even by non-tech personal

Answer (score 1):

Once you got the Google Analytics -> BigQuery data transfer setup and data starts to flow.

You can have export jobs that produces files on Google Cloud Storage in multiple files.

Then from GCS you can download those files to your location.

Pleas be advised that best would first to query and clean data in BQ, as it will be easier rather then parsing the exported files again.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data